# PHP Create zip but exclude zip file

Tags: php, zip

I am using a create zip file in PHP but I want to exclude the zip file itself.

```
$rootPath = realpath('../../');

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open('../../includes/updatenew.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file)
    {
        if (!$file->isDir())
        {
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

            $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
        }
    }
    $zip->close();
```

This code first creates the ../../includes/updatenew.zip and then zips the whole directory, but how can I exclude the updatenew.zip from being added in the zip?

Answer (score 1):

update your condition from

```
if (!$file->isDir())
```

to something similar to

```
if (!$file->isDir() AND (strpos($name, 'updatenew.zip') === FALSE))
```

This will skip all files which contain 'updatenew.zip' in the name of the file.